# Laravel eloquent find max(date) with additional search criteria

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out the best way to retrieve results from the database such that the `created_at` is the most recent, and also checking that another value (in this case Temps->value) matches a specific criteria..

For example (some information abbreviated)

**LOCATIONS**

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  CITY   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | DALLAS  |
|  2 | CHICAGO |
|  3 | ATLANTA |
+----+---------+
```

**TEMPS**

```
+----+-------+----------+------------+
| ID | VALUE | CITY_ID  | CREATED_AT |
+----+-------+----------+------------+
|  1 |    70 |        1 |       2010 |
|  2 |    95 |        1 |       2015 |
|  3 |    90 |        2 |       2010 |
|  4 |    80 |        2 |       2015 |
|  5 |    99 |        3 |       2015 |
+----+-------+----------+------------+
```

my location model.

```
class Location extends model
{
...
   public function latestValue()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Temp')->latest();
   }
```

In this case I would only like the Locations in which the **latest** temperature reading is > 90..

In my controller if have

```
$highTemps = Location::with('latestValue')->get();
```

without iterating through every city explicitly, is there a way to adjust my eloquent relationship, or even use a collection method to filter the results?

I've looked at `filter()` but I'm not sure how to use that on a relationship.  Especially if you're trying to filter 2-3 relationships deep. (imagine I'm starting off with Country->states->locations->temps->latestValue etc)

It would be great to have the initial query filter the results.  But I can't figure out the combination of `groupBy()` and `max()` and `having()` etc to make the eloquent statement work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Relationship you are establishing, it's wrong..
The Problem is very simple if the relationship `hasMany()` will be used..

First all the latest entries will be fetched , followed by filtering the `max` out of them.

```
class Location extends model
{
...
   public function latestValue()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Temp')->latest();
   }
```

rest is not that much typical i assume.